# Tikz-timing: using an arrow for a vertical line like G (glitch) symbol?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-timing

I just asked this question: [Does the program counter always have to change (upon an instruction tick)? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695950/does-the-program-counter-always-have-to-change-upon-an-instruction-tick), where I used the following code:

```
% min-timing.tex
% pdflatex min-timing.tex                               # to obtain min-timing.pdf
% convert -density 300x min-timing.pdf min-timing.png   # to obtain min-timing.png

% \documentclass[border=0]{standalone} % incorrectly crops image - use minimal + preview
\documentclass{minimal}

% minimal doesn't have \scriptsize, \tiny:
\makeatletter
\def\scriptsize{\@setfontsize{\scriptsize}{7}{8pt}}
\def\tiny{\@setfontsize{\tiny}{5}{6pt}}
\def\ttiny{\@setfontsize{\ttiny}{4}{5pt}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes,snakes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary[rising arrows]{clockarrows}
\usetikztiminglibrary{advnodes}

\usepackage[graphics,tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\newlength{\imagescale}

\usepackage{helvet}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikztimingtable}[%
    timing/nodes/advanced,
    timing/dslope=0.1,
    timing/name/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
    timing/d/text/.style={font=\sffamily\ttiny},
  ]
  %
  % start timing diagram
  %
  \textcolor{black}{Instruction} & [black]
    Z 2D{push}    4D{mov}     4D{sub}     4D{movl}    4D{mov}     2D{leave}   2D{ret}     2D{...} \\ %
  \textcolor{black}{PC Address} & [black]
    Z 2D{8048394} 4D{8048395} 4D{8048397} 4D{804839a} 4D{80483a1} 2D{80483a4} 2D{80483a5} 2D{...} \\ %
  \textcolor{red}{Instruction tick} & [red]
    S G 2{S}      G 4{S}      G 4{S}      G 4{S}      G 4{S}      G 2{S}      G 2{S}      G 2{S}  \\ %
  \textcolor{brown}{Clock} & [brown]
    Z 2{C}        4{C}        4{C}        4{C}        4{C}        2{C}        2{C}        2{C}    \\ %
  %
  % end timing diagram
  %
  % there must NOT be an uncommented line before \extracode!
  %
\extracode
  \tablerules
  \tablegrid
\end{tikztimingtable}

\end{document}
```

... to obtain this image:

[image: min-timing.png]

I was wandering - (how) is it possible to have the G (glitch) symbols in "Instruction tick" be rendered as an "up arrow", like the rising clock edge?

Comment: Calling @Martin Scharrer for great justice :)

Comment: In the meantime, you might want to check where `G` is parsed and put a `[->]` (or `[<-]`).

Comment: Cheers @percusse - missed that possibility - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `arrows` library and then can use `A` for an upwards arrow (A = Arrow) and `W` for an downwards arrow (W = arroW). After the arrow a length according to the timing letter width is inserted. This means `4A` is equal to `G 4S`.

So what you need is:

```
  \textcolor{red}{Instruction tick} & [red]
    S 2A          4A          4A          4A          4A          2A          2A          2A      \
```

after loading:

```
\usetikztiminglibrary{arrows}
```

This gives:

[image: Result]

Please see the manual for more information and examples on that library.

---

BTW: Note that you don't need to use `4{S}` to get a space of 4. You can use `4S` directly. The difference is that `4S` makes a space with width 4 directly, while `4{S}` is turned into `SSSS` internally by the *repetition* `{ }` code and then combined to `4S` by the internal optimizer, which is of course less efficient as writing `4S` directly.

Comment: Awesome - that looks pretty good, many thanks @Martin Scharrer! Also thanks for the `S` note... Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two options:
either replace all glitch signals with arrows (`0A` instead of `G`):

```
\textcolor{red}{Instruction tick} & [red]
S 0A 2{S}      0A 4{S}      0A 4{S}      0A 4{S}      0A 4{S}      0A 2{S}      0A 2{S}      0A 2{S}  \\ %
```

You will need to specify `0A` to preserve spacing between the signals (simply `A` won't do, as it inserts extra space behind the symbol). Also, you will need to load the `arrows` timing library: `\usetikztiminglibrary{arrows}`

Or, if you want to make the code semantically correct, use overlays (I would suggest this one, although it is a tiny bit more verbose than than the previous one):

```
\textcolor{red}{Instruction tick} & [red]
S O{A}{G} 2{S}      O{A}{G} 4{S}      O{A}{G} 4{S}      O{A}{G} 4{S}      O{A}{G} 4{S}      O{A}{G} 2{S}      O{A}{G} 2{S}      O{A}{G} 2{S}  \\ %
```

Again, you will need the `arrows` library and additionally the `overlays` library: `\usetikztiminglibrary{arrows, overlays}`.

Comment: Yes, `arrows` is the way to got and was written by me just for such diagrams. However, you can do it better (see also my answer): the space which is part of `A` is intended to avoid the need of explicit `S`s, so instead of `0A 2{S}` (which should be written as `0A 2S` anyway) you can write simply `2S`. I don't get the "semantically correct" part and wouldn't use overlays of `A` and `G`. After all, the diagrams doesn't show logical glitches.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: With "semantically correct" I just meant that the intention of the author was to visualize glitches and the 'markup' for them is `G`. In order to show that in the code, I thought an overlay could be used. Of course this is unnecessary, partly also because the typographic effect is the same.

Comment: I don't think so. He just used `G` as a marker, not as his intended function, which is to be placed in normal signals, e.g. `LGL`. Note that `G` doesn't interrupt the path because of this and therefore `timing/g/.style={->}` doesn't work.

Comment: Just to confirm - I indeed used `G` as a marker, not as a glitch; I simply missed realizing `A` is a more appropriate symbol at the time, and `G` was the closest one to a "vertical marker", that is why I used it ... Thanks for the comments - cheers!