# Inserting a rising-edge arrow on a \texttiming macro in tikz-timing

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-timing

I am creating a table for a circuit that is affected by the rising edge of the clock, and I want to show that. Right now, I am using the `tikz-timing` package, and using the `\texttiming{LH}` command to generate symbol. Although it doesn't have an arrow on the vertical, which is what I really want. I have explored using just plain old tikz drawings, but I need the symbol in a table, and the tikz drawings wouldn't render in the cell.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
            \texttiming{LH} & This is what I have \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Timing symbol]

I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30901/tikz-timing-using-an-arrow-for-a-vertical-line-like-g-glitch-symbol) but it didn't help, since I just need the text symbol, and not a diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all of the help. I actually didn't see the responses before I fixed the problem. Here is the response I came up with.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary[rising arrows]{clockarrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
                \texttiming{LH} & This is what I had \\\hline
        k       \texttiming[timing/c/rising arrows, timing/c/arrow pos=.7]{2{C}} & This is what I wanted \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is what that produces. [image: Clock with rising edge arrow]

I found this by reading through the tikz-timing manual located [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-timing/tikz-timing.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I created a macro that draws the symbol `raisedge`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\raiseedge{{\scriptsize\tikz[scale = 0.22, baseline=(b.base), >=stealth]{
      \draw[->] (0, 0) node(b){} -- ++(0:1) -- ++(80:1) -- ++(0:1);}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    \raiseedge & This is what I have \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on @caverac's answer, just moving the arrow to the middle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\newcommand*\raiseedge{{\scriptsize\tikz[scale = 0.22, baseline=(b.base), >=stealth]{
      \draw[-,postaction={decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{>}}},decorate}
      ] (0, 0) node(b){} -- ++(0:1) -- ++(80:1) -- ++(0:1);}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    \raiseedge & This is what I have \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice catch!! +1